# split binary file into chunks or Parts upload / download

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, couchdb

I am using couchdb for some reason as a content management to upload files as binary data, there is no GridFs support like mongoDB to upload large files, so I need to upload files as chunks then retrieve them as one file.

here is my code

```cs
  public string InsertDataToCouchDb(string dbName, string id, string filename, byte[] image)
  {
    var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CouchDb"].ConnectionString;
    using (var db = new MyCouchClient(connection, dbName))
    {

      // HERE I NEED TO UPLOAD MY IMAGE BYTE[] AS CHUNKS 
      var artist = new couchdb
      {
        _id = id,
        filename = filename,
        Image = image
      };

      var response = db.Entities.PutAsync(artist);
      return response.Result.Content._id;
    }
  }

  public byte[] FetchDataFromCouchDb(string dbName, string id)
  {
    var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CouchDb"].ConnectionString;
    using (var db = new MyCouchClient(connection, dbName))
    {
      //HERE I NEED TO RETRIVE MY FULL IMAGE[] FROM CHUNKS
      var test = db.Documents.GetAsync(id, null);
      var doc = db.Serializer.Deserialize<couchdb>(test.Result.Content);
      return doc.Image;
    }
  }
```

THANK YOU

Comment: You are making async calls but not using `await`.  This won't even compile?

Comment: Also, storing images in the doc as opposed to an attachment is a poor design choice. Especially if an image is not of a trivial in size!

Answer (score 1):

Putting image data in a CouchDB document is a ***terrible idea***.  Just don't. This is the purpose of [CouchDB attachments](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/api.html?highlight=attachments#attachments).
The potential of bloating the database with redundant blob data via document updates alone will surely have major, negative consequences for anything other than a toy database.

Further there seems to be a lack of understanding how async/await works as the code in the OP is invoking async methods, e.g. `db.Entities.PutAsync(artist)`,  without an `await` - the call surely will fail every time (if the compiler even allows the code).  I highly recommend grok'ing the Microsoft document [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Now as for "chunking": If the image data is so large that it needs to be otherwise streamed, the business of passing it around via a byte array looks bad. If the images are relatively small, just use `Attachment.PutAsync` as it stands.

Although `Attachment.PutAsync` at MyCouch v7.6 does not support streams (effectively chunking) there exists the [Support Streams for attachments #177](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/pull/177) PR, which does, and it looks pretty good.

Here's a one page C# .Net Core console app that uploads a given file as an attachment to a specific document using the very efficient streaming provided by PR 177.  Although the code uses PR 177, it most importantly uses Attachments for blob data.  Replacing a stream with a byte array is rather straightforward.

###### MyCouch + PR 177

In a console get MyCouch sources and then apply PR 177

```
$ git clone https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch.git
$ cd mycouch
$ git pull origin 15a1079502a1728acfbfea89a7e255d0c8725e07
```

(I don't know git so there's probably a far better way to get a PR)

###### MyCouchUploader

With VS2019

1. Create a new .Net Core console app project and solution named "MyCouchUploader"
2. Add the MyCouch project pulled with PR 177 to the solution
3. Add the MyCouch project as MyCouchUploader dependency
4. Add the Nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" as a MyCouchUploader dependency
5. Replace the content of Program.cs with the following code:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using MyCouch;
using MyCouch.Requests;
using MyCouch.Responses;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyCouchUploader
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // args: scheme, database, file path of asset to upload.
            if (args.Length < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUsage: MyCouchUploader scheme dbname filepath\n");
                return;
            }

            var opts = new
            {
                scheme = args[0],
                dbName = args[1],
                filePath = args[2]
            };
            
            Action<Response> check = (response) =>
            {
                if (!response.IsSuccess) throw new Exception(response.Reason);
            };

            try
            {
                // canned doc id for this app
                const string docId = "SO-68998781";
                const string attachmentName = "Image";

                DbConnectionInfo cnxn = new DbConnectionInfo(opts.scheme, opts.dbName)
                { // timely fail if scheme is bad
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000)
                };
                MyCouchClient client = new MyCouchClient(cnxn);
                // ensure db is there
                GetDatabaseResponse info = await client.Database.GetAsync();
                check(info);
                // delete doc for succcessive program runs 
                DocumentResponse doc = await client.Documents.GetAsync(docId);
                if (doc.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    DocumentHeaderResponse del = await client.Documents.DeleteAsync(docId, doc.Rev);
                    check(del);
                }
                // sniff file for content type
                FileExtensionContentTypeProvider provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
                if (!provider.TryGetContentType(opts.filePath, out string contentType))
                {
                    contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                }
                
                // create a hash for silly verification
                using var md5 = MD5.Create();                
                using Stream stream = File.OpenRead(opts.filePath);
                byte[] fileHash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

                stream.Position = 0;
                // Use PR 177, sea-locks:stream-attachments.
                DocumentHeaderResponse put = await client.Attachments.PutAsync(new PutAttachmentStreamRequest(
                    docId,
                    attachmentName,
                    contentType,
                    stream // :-D
                ));
                check(put);                                

                // verify 
                AttachmentResponse verify = await client.Attachments.GetAsync(docId, attachmentName);
                check(verify);                 
                if (fileHash.SequenceEqual(md5.ComputeHash(verify.Content)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Atttachment verified.");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Attachment failed verification with status code {0}", verify.StatusCode));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail! {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To run:

```
$ MyCouchdbUploader http://name:password@localhost:5984 dbname path-to-local-image-file
```

Use Fauxton to visually verify the attachment for the doc.

Comment: There are PDF files with around size of 1 GB which needs to upload in CouchDB with Bulk Import with effective time. So if you can guide me in this requirement

Comment: 1G? Wow, that's impressive.  Passing a 1G data via `byte[]`...definitely need to use [PR 177](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/pull/177) for `Attachment.PutAsync` if using MyCouch. It would've been an *epic mistake* to store assets of that size in the body of a CouchDB document. I feel my answer is good as it stands - your follow-up question lends to server configuration and system architecture, not programming, and thus best asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) and [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Good luck!